# How to apply outer limit offset and filters in the subquery to avoid grouping over the complete table used in subquery in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join, performance, group-by, subquery, postgresql-performance

I have legacy tables similar to the following:

**employee**

```
------------------------------------
|  employee_id  |   name    
------------------------------------
|  1            |   David    
|  2            |  Mathew  
------------------------------------
```

**payroll**

```
-------------------------------------
|  employee_id  | salary      
-------------------------------------
|   2           |  200000    
|   3           |  90000      
-------------------------------------
```

I want to get the following data, after joins and filters:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  address_id  | employee_id  |  address        
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   1          |  2           |  street 1, NY  
|   2          |  2           |  street 2, DC  
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT employee_id, salary, address_arr 
FROM employee 
LEFT JOIN payroll on payroll.employee_id = employee.employee_id
INNER JOIN 
     (
       SELECT employee_id, ARRAY_AGG(address) as address_arr 
       FROM addresses 
       GROUP BY employee_id
     ) table_address ON table_address.employee_id = employee.employee_id
WHERE employee.employee_id < 1000000
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0
```

Above query gives the desired output but is highly unoptimized as the `GROUP BY` operation occurs over the complete addresses table before being used for `JOIN` operation the outer query.

Kindly answer:

1. How can we avoid the `GROUP BY` operation to occurs over the complete
   addresses table by using `LIMIT OFFSET` of the outer query?
2. Will the condition `WHERE employee.employee_id < 1000000` be applied on subquery before or after the `GROUP BY` operation in the inner query. If the condition is applied after the `GROUP BY`, how can we avoid that?

Note: There are multiple `JOIN`s and subqueries in the actual query being used.

Comment: PS. LIMIT without ORDER BY gives you 100 random records from the whole data array... do you really need in that?

Comment: You should present us the simplest query you can which still have the issue.  If you remove the left join on PAYROLL, does the problem go away?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is really more efficient, but you could try to join to a derived table that applies the limit.

```
select emp.employee_id, emp.salary, adr.address_arr 
from (
  SELECT employee_id, salary, address_arr 
  FROM employee 
    LEFT JOIN payroll on payroll.employee_id = employee.employee_id
  WHERE employee.employee_id < 1000000
  LIMIT 100
  OFFSET 0
) as emp
  JOIN (
     SELECT a.employee_id, ARRAY_AGG(a.address) as address_arr 
     FROM addresses a
     GROUP BY employee_id
  ) as adr ON adr.employee_id = emp.employee_id;
```

The first derived table only selects 100 rows, and the join/group by should then only be done for those 100 employees.

If the optimizer doesn't push that down, you could try a lateral join instead to "force" a push down:

```
select emp.employee_id, emp.salary, adr.address_arr 
from (
  SELECT employee_id, salary, address_arr 
  FROM employee 
    LEFT JOIN payroll on payroll.employee_id = employee.employee_id
  WHERE employee.employee_id < 1000000
  LIMIT 100
  OFFSET 0
) as emp
  LATERAL JOIN (
     SELECT a.employee_id, ARRAY_AGG(a.address) as address_arr 
     FROM addresses a
     WHERE a.employee_id = emp.employee_id
     GROUP BY employee_id
  ) as adr ON adr.employee_id = emp.employee_id;
```

The join condition isn't really needed, but it dosn't hurt either

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
SELECT employee.employee_id, payroll.salary, ARRAY_AGG(addresses.address)
FROM employee 
INNER JOIN addresses ON addresses.employee_id = employee.employee_id
LEFT JOIN payroll on payroll.employee_id = employee.employee_id
WHERE employee.employee_id < 1000000
GROUP BY employee.employee_id
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0
```

?

And - do you really need in records where no appropriate records in `payroll` table which leads to NULLs in `payroll.salary`? Maybe, INNER JOIN is enough?

Comment: The query is incorrect. payroll.salary needs to be included in GROUP BY clause, which will unoptimise the query further

Comment: @nimeshkiranverma *payroll.salary needs to be included in GROUP BY clause* you may wrap it using any aggregate function which can be applied to this field datatype.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this and had some help , here's what I came up with:

```
with t as (SELECT employee.employee_id, salary  FROM employee  LEFT JOIN payroll on payroll.employee_id = employee.employee_id WHERE employee.employee_id < 1000000 LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0)
select t.employee_id, max(t.salary), ARRAY_AGG(address) as address_arr from address left join t on address.employee_id = t.employee_id where address.employee_id = t.employee_id group by t.employee_id;
```

explain analyze yields

```
HashAggregate  (cost=443931.83..443933.08 rows=100 width=44) (actual time=3173.705..3173.705 rows=1 loops=1)
   Group Key: t.employee_id
   CTE t
     ->  Limit  (cost=313.99..316.90 rows=100 width=12) (actual time=7.441..7.511 rows=100 loops=1)
           ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=313.99..145616.13 rows=4983381 width=12) (actual time=7.437..7.490 rows=100 loops=1)
                 Hash Cond: (payroll.employee_id = employee.employee_id)
                 ->  Seq Scan on payroll  (cost=0.00..76778.79 rows=4983879 width=12) (actual time=0.036..0.047 rows=100 loops=1)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=189.00..189.00 rows=9999 width=4) (actual time=7.370..7.370 rows=10000 loops=1)
                       Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 480kB
                       ->  Seq Scan on employee  (cost=0.00..189.00 rows=9999 width=4) (actual time=0.016..3.783 rows=10000 loops=1)
                             Filter: (employee_id < 1000000)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.25..441981.29 rows=217817 width=37) (actual time=7.699..3119.096 rows=200000 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (address.employee_id = t.employee_id)
         ->  Seq Scan on address  (cost=0.00..364792.00 rows=20002100 width=29) (actual time=0.067..1568.256 rows=20000000 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=2.00..2.00 rows=100 width=12) (actual time=7.609..7.609 rows=100 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
               ->  CTE Scan on t  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=12) (actual time=7.449..7.580 rows=100 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.456 ms
 Execution time: 3174.499 ms
(19 rows)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give us the explain output in plain text please ?