# How to take make OFFSET & LIMIT with COUNT (OVER?) when having a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, window-functions, offset-fetch

It appears I have a case I can't quite wrap my brains around. So coming here in hopes to find pointers to a query that maybe could be helpful to someone else too.

In the following, I have a query that functions correctly as far returning results goes but requires a second query that is the same as the one presented here but without `OFFSET` and the output is just a `COUNT(*)` of all of the rows.

I have two objectives:

1. Write the query so that `COUNT(*)` is returned in the same query. Indeed I have been looking at help pieces such as the excellent [SQL SERVER – How to get total row count from OFFSET / FETCH NEXT (Paging)](https://raresql.com/2015/03/30/sql-server-how-to-get-total-row-count-from-offset-fetch-next-paging/) with different ways of solving the problem, but then there's another piece...
2. Rewrite the join with a window function (e.g. `OVER(PARTITION BY`) or some more performant way as that query seem to generate an `INDEX SCAN` and `INDEX SEEK` on the table. The real query is a bit more complicated in the `WHERE` part, but it looks to me even one scan could be enough if the query were a bit more straightforward so that the `COUNT` and `MAX` could be had simultaneously with the outer query. Even this would be a win, but combined with having the overall `COUNT` would be even bigger.

Maybe I'm trying to chew a teeny bit more than I can chew currently, but on the other hand, maybe there is now a chance to learn something.

Here are the table and data

```
CREATE TABLE Temp
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Created INT NOT NULL,
    ParentId INT,
    SomeInfo INT NOT NULL,
    GroupId INT NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT FK_Temp FOREIGN KEY(ParentId) REFERENCES Temp(Id)
);

-- Some root levels nodes.
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(1, 1, NULL, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(2, 2, NULL, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(3, 3, NULL, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(13, 13, NULL, 1, 1);

-- First order child nodes.
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(4, 4, 1, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(5, 5, 2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(6, 6, 3, 2, 3);

-- Second order child nodes.
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(7, 7, 4, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(8, 8, 5, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(9, 9, 6, 1, 3);

SELECT
    Id,
    newestTable.SomeInfo,
    newestTable.Created,
    CASE WHEN newestTable.RootCount > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsMulti
FROM
   Temp as originalTable
   INNER JOIN
   (
        SELECT
            SomeInfo,
            Max(Created) AS Created,
            Count(*) AS RootCount
        FROM
            Temp
        WHERE ParentId IS NULL AND GroupId = 1
        GROUP BY SomeInfo
    ) AS newestTable ON originalTable.SomeInfo = newestTable.SomeInfo AND originalTable.Created = newestTable.Created
/*WHERE
(
    originalTable.SomeInfo = 1
)*/
ORDER BY newestTable.Created ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

P.S. Also [How to apply outer limit offset and filters in the subquery to avoid grouping over the complete table used in subquery in Postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229214/how-to-apply-outer-limit-offset-and-filters-in-the-subquery-to-avoid-grouping-ov) looks interesting.

<edit:

It looks like

```
SELECT
    Id,
    SomeInfo,
    GroupId,
    ParentId,
    MAX(Created) OVER(PARTITION BY SomeInfo) AS Created,
    COUNT(Id) OVER(PARTITION BY SomeInfo) AS RootCount,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(Id) OVER(PARTITION BY SomeInfo) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsMulti
FROM
    Temp
WHERE
(
    GroupId = 1 AND ParentId IS NULL
)
ORDER BY Created ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

gets close to there. The problem is, though, there are now two result rows and it appears to me this is due to the original `INNER JOIN` joining back to `Temp` that cull it to one row. I wonder if there is a way to apply the conditions somehow either before or after the windowing to match more closely the original query. (And this isn't the same query, to be clear. There's just so little data, hence the queries look like being close to each other.)

Comment: So I have a couple of questions.  1) What is the purpose of the `Created` column?  Since it seems to match `ID` each time I don't understand why we are trying to get a `MAX` of that value. 2) Are you going to use the `ID` column in something else after the fact?  If you are not then you should be able to handle everything you need with just a single query.

Comment: The `Created` column is some point in time (monotonically increasing) that is the time the entry is created. In hindsight I should not have simplified this case and I should have used `DATETIME`. The match of values between identity and created is accidental on my part. The Id is needed, it's something that is needed from the parent table (in some other sense it could be any value from `originalTable`.

I tried to replicate a case I have seen IRL that I think could be done better. I probably work on this tomorrow again (it's almost midnight here, need to sleep). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like to me what you are missing is the "Return only the top `Created` record for each instance".  So you are getting all rows, and then watever its top `Created` value is for the same `SomeInfo` record.  Unfortunately you can't just add the `MAX(Created) = Created` into the base `WHERE` clause.

If you just wrap the whole thing in a `CTE` you can then just add a `MAX(Created) = Created` into the `WHERE` and get what you are looking for (not that i think `CTE`'s are the anwer for everything).

```
WITH CTE (ID, SomeInfo, GroupID, ParentID, Created, MaxCreated, RootCount, IsMulti)
AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        SomeInfo,
        GroupId,
        ParentId,
        Created,
        MAX(Created) OVER(PARTITION BY SomeInfo) AS MaxCreated,
        COUNT(Id) OVER(PARTITION BY SomeInfo) AS RootCount,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(Id) OVER(PARTITION BY SomeInfo) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsMulti
    FROM
        Temp
)
SELECT ID, SomeInfo, GroupID, ParentID,  MaxCreated AS Created, RootCount, IsMulti
FROM CTE
WHERE
(
    GroupId = 1 
    AND ParentId IS NULL
    AND Created = MaxCreated
)
ORDER BY MaxCreated ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

In my quick test it has the same execution plan and does not take any additional execution time (See execution plan added below). (now it is a small result set so it is probably something you will still need to test with.)

[image: Execution Plan from Test]

Hopefully that is more of what you are looking for.

Comment: I'll think about this, maybe this gives some additional ideas. I added my thoughts, a new query, about the ideas I've been mulling. I'm wondering if there's a way to do the condition in the original query somehow efficiently while winding or to apply it afterwards to the results. Maybe this gives some new ideas, thank you for taking the time to give thoughts.

Comment: @Veksi Just updated this with a 2nd version that might do everything you are looking for without having to do an additional lookup.  it does use a `CTE` but it doesn't appear to impact the execution plan at all.

Comment: I think it's correct when the outer `WHERE` is moved to the `CTE`. Then taking a clue from the linked OFFSET-LIMIT-COUNT article one can add a second CTE (`Count_CTE`) that counts the rows in the first CTE and then selecting both one can actually combine the overall count with OFFSET-LIMIT and have this more complex, combined, query to be equally efficient as initial one with join to a subquery. But naturally since one doesn't need to issue a separate `COUNT` query, it saves one heavy query.

Comment: You are a persistent guy. Much appreciated your effort, do tell if my added explanation doesn't make sense and I clarify.

Comment: @Veksi The `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;` should be filtering the final result set to the first five rows of whatever is returned in the order specified.  I guess I don't understand what you are looking to have accomplished with the 2nd `CTE`.  Maybe I just need more data to to see the specific use case.  Would we be able to get those details in your Question post?